# Constants and aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have constants in my cs file Constants.cs.  In the asp.net mvc controllers I use the constants like this ViewData[Constants.Whatever] = ...;

How can I use the constants in my aspx file?  When I try to use it I get an error saying:

CS0103: The name 'Constants' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Could this be a namespace issue?  Include the namespace in your web.config file.  look for add namespace i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the namespace of class on the web.config so it can recognize it ... probably

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
```

Change **System.Collections.Generic** with the namespace where you declare your Contants.cs code file so that it gets into the scope.

Answer (score 0):

What namespace is your `Constants` class is in? You have to import it; say it's `Foo.App.Constants` (i.e. namespace `Foo.App`), you'll want to add

```
 <%@ Import Namespace="Foo.App" %>
```

to the top of your aspx file.